Requests module cannot connect to target website when I take my laptop to the company
requests works fine at home, but it could not work when i take my laptop to the company using the network from the company, it says socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, a DNS problem?
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com"

response = requests.get(url)

At the company, i could visit google via the browser chrome or egde, both works fine with no issue, so the netwrok should be OK i guess, and it is using an automatic Configuration script (.js) to take care the network setting.
i happen to try pip install xxx, it does not work either and says the same: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')'
with that, i guess it is not about the requests module, it might be the networking setting for python when i'm connecting to the company's network?

When you say it is using an automatic configuration script, what do you mean exactly? Do you have an IT department in your office that could tell you if there are any security measures in place on their network?
